# Gremlin arithmetic on where predicate?

Tags: gremlin

In this question [Gremlin graph traversal that uses previous edge property value to filter later edges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40165426/gremlin-graph-traversal-that-uses-previous-edge-property-value-to-filter-later-e) we can use where to compare property of edge. I don't want just using simple `neq` or `eq` or `gt`. Can gremlin support on arithmetic on this two edge? suck like `gtv('firstEdge', 0.2)` or `g.V(1).outE().has('weight',1.0).as('firstEdge').inV().outE().as('secondEdge').filter((secondEdge-firstEdge) > 0.2)`

I seem don't find such thing in document.

Comment: This can be done several ways. You could use `math` or `sack`, and couple them with the `where.....by` structure. I will add an example in an answer a bit later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to approach a situation like this. For simple queries where you just want `a+b < some value`, using `sack` works well. For example, using the air-routes data set:

```java
g.withSack(0).
  V('44').
  repeat(outE('route').sack(sum).by('dist').inV().simplePath()).
  times(2).
  where(sack().is(lt(500))).
  path().
    by('code').
    by('dist').
  limit(2)
```

which yields:

```
1   path[SAF, 369, PHX, 110, TUS]
2   path[SAF, 369, PHX, 119, FLG]
```

To use the `math` step requires just a little more work:

Let's first just see how the `math` step works in such a case via a query to take the difference between some route distances:

```java
g.V('44').
  outE('route').as('a').inV().
  outE('route').as('b').inV().
  project('b','a','diff').
    by(select('b').values('dist')).
    by(select('a').values('dist')).
    by(math('b - a').by('dist')).
  limit(3)
```

which yields:

```
1   {'b': 1185, 'a': 549, 'diff': 636.0}
2   {'b': 6257, 'a': 549, 'diff': 5708.0}
3   {'b': 8053, 'a': 549, 'diff': 7504.0}
```

we can now refine the query to find routes where the difference is less than 100.

```java
g.V('44').
  outE('route').as('a').inV().
  outE('route').as('b').inV().
  where(math('b - a').by('dist').is(lt(100))).
  path().
    by('code').
    by('dist').
  limit(3)
```

which gives us:

```
1   path[SAF, 549, DFW, 430, MEM]
2   path[SAF, 549, DFW, 461, MCI]
3   path[SAF, 549, DFW, 550, STL]
```

you can also use the absolute value in the calculation if preferred:

```java
g.V('44').
  outE('route').as('a').inV().
  outE('route').as('b').inV().
  where(math('abs(b - a)').by('dist').is(lt(100))).
  path().
    by('code').
    by('dist').
  limit(3)
```

Comment: A little more question. if the property type is `datetime` the `-` is not ok. I am thinking two method ： 1. transform date to int, but how to named the computed property 2. custom sub for `datetime` ?

Comment: Currently, Gremlin has no way to do calculations on dates. It is something we would like to see added to the language. In the near term storing the dates as epoch integers is likely the best way to do this.